# how can say with one word or shortly that three meal service of day

Tags: word-choice

how can describe with one word or shortly that three meal service of day in the a rest menu. Breakfast+lunch+dinner= what would be described

Comment: "Breakfast, lunch, and dinner served"?  That's how I would state it.  I don't think there is just one word that says what you want.

Comment: Or "Open 6AM to 10PM".  For a restaurant, those hours would imply that breakfast, lunch, and dinner are served.  You need to provide more context. Where/why do you want to make this statement?

Comment: They could convey that with something like, "Any meal, any time", but there isn't a standard expression for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such word. "Serving breakfast, lunch, and dinner" is probably the most succinct way. Or simply "Breakfast served 8:00 - 11:00 a.m." and the customer will assume they can get the usual meals all other hours of the day.